# Java Regex Multiple Pattern Group Replace

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Say I have the following string

```
String Context = "old1 old2 old3 old4 old5 old6"
```

I wish to do a pattern: `(old2).*(old4)`

so word 2 would be in `$1` and word4 would be in `$2`.

Is there any functions or methods that i can replace the two words strings at the same time? Using only the group variable (`$1` and `$2`) ?

So I could specify that `$1` will become `new2` and `$2` will become `new4`.
I don't want to have to find the string `old2` and `old4` and replace it to `new2` and `new4`

Comment: Use [java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with the Matcher.

Comment: Can you explain more what do you mean by your last sentence "*I don't want to have to find the string old2 and old4 and replace it to new2 and new4*"? It seems that you want to do exactly what you described here, find `old2` and `old4` and replace it with `new2` and `new4`.

Answer (score 4):

**Only One Group Needed**

If I am understanding, this is what you need:

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("old2(.*?)old4", "new2$1new4");
```

**Explanation**

- `old2` matches literal chars
- `(.*?)` lazily matches chars (capturing them to Group 1), up to...
- `old4`
- Replace with `new2`, the content of Group 1 and `new4`

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using a **Positive Lookahead** here.

```
String s = "old1 old2 old3 old4 old5 old6";
String r = s.replaceAll("old(?=[24])", "new");
System.out.println(r); //=> "old1 new2 old3 new4 old5 old6"
```

[Lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) are zero-width assertions. They don't consume any characters on the string.

This will remove "old" replacing it with "new" asserting that either (`2` or `4`) follows..

Comment: I am not sure if this is what OP really wants, but +1 since it answers question as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple `replace`

```
 "old1 old2 old3 old4 old5 old6".replace("old2", "new2").replace("old4", "new4");
```

of course the original String and the replace target and replace replacement can be variables.

Comment: This is possibly error prone solution. What if OP will want to swap old2 and old4 places? By replacing `old2` with `old4` first time and then replacing `old4` with `old2` you will end up only with `old2`, with no `old4`.

Comment: Yes, whilst this is not an idiot proof solution, I feel that for a newbie it is an easy to read and understand solution.  I am not sure of the OP java level or his real intent, so whether it is suitable for him or not is not known.